# Can I override PageImpl in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

There are a few methods that I would like to incorporate into PageImpl. Is there anyway I could override the default Page Implementation returned by Spring Data's repository methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add some methods, you could use aspectJ do to so. Something like:

```
public privileged aspect PageImplAspect {

    public boolean PageImpl.isEmpty() {
        // you implementation here.
    } 
}
```

You will need to instruct aspectj compiler to wave springdata library, this can be done in Maven using weaveDependencies in aspectj-maven-plugin plugin.

Comment: Interesting... we're not using AspectJ at our company but I'll look into this. Thanks.